# How to fix 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'

Tags: reactjs

I am pulling data from JSON api. I am assigning a key in the unique element generated by the map function, yet i cannot figure out why i am still seeing this warning. Where do i need to assign the key?

```
import React from 'react';
import PokeCell from './PokeCell';
import './styles/PokeList.css';

const PokeList = (props) => {

return (
    <section className="poke-list">
        {props.pokemon.map((pokemon) => (
            <PokeCell 
                key={pokemon.id}
                id={pokemon.id}
                name={pokemon.name}
                image={pokemon.image}
            />
         ))}
    </section>
 )
}

export default PokeList;

index.js:1375 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" 
prop.

Check the render method of `PokeList`
    in PokeCell (at PokeList.js:10)
    in PokeList (at App.js:24)
    in div (at App.js:20)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

Comment: You're putting the key in the right place... right before your return call can you `clg` the ids of props.pokemon?

Comment: pokemon.id has valid values right?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of array `index` to have unique key.

```
<section className="poke-list">
    {props.pokemon.map((pokemon, index) => (
        <PokeCell 
            key={pokemon.id + index}
            id={pokemon.id}
            name={pokemon.name}
            image={pokemon.image}
        />
     ))}
</section>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! I guess the pokemond.id wasn't unique like i thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure, that each id is unique to enable react to update the components correctly.

You should not use the index as a key value, since removing items from the list or reordering it, may cause bugs.

You have to make sure, that each id is unique across all possible configuration of the list (adding, removing etc) to prevent unnecessary rerendering as well.

You should keep that implementation and change how you safe your data to provide unique ids.